# UITableView, Image in cell isn't showing, despite showing in UI View Hierachy inspector

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, asynchronous

I use a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`s. In the cells I have a `UIImageView`. I assign an image to that image view from a url from my model. All this have been working fine until now.

When the cell is returned in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the image is fetched through a UIImageView extension and assigned to the `image` property when the async fetch returns.

The image doesn't show in the UIImageView, dispite having worked before (maybe this problem occured after Xcode 8 was released)

What's even more strange, it appear right in the UI View Hierachy Inspector in Xcode.

**What's going on??**

**Screenshot from device:**

[image: Screenshot from device]

**Screenshot from UI View Hierachy Inspector in Xcode**

[image]

Comment: Are you changing the corner radius of the image anywhere in code?

Comment: Yes! in the cell.. In `awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code that changes corner radius from awakeFromNib to layoutSubviews in your cell subclass like the example below. This should fix it.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(imageView.bounds) / 2.0
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: You are right. The problem is that the bounds of the ImageView are very large at the awakeFromNib. It didn't solve my problem to move it to layourSubviews. This isn't called when the image returns. I solved the problem by just setting the cornerradius to a constant number.

Comment: Adding self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded() after super.layoutSubviews() may help with the imageView size in layoutSubviews.

Comment: After adding self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded(), the imageView.bounds has the rigth size, and images gets displayed properly.. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! Adding that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try changing it in your `tableView` class.

Like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! yourCellClassName //Change this to your cell

        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        return cell
   }
```

Hope it will help you.