# Xcode 8 - UITable not rendering cells properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode8

I have tested the app in Xcode7 and 8.
This issue only happens in Xcode 8. I know it's wierd.

As you can see in the picture below the image avatar is not rendering, but if you scrolls then images avatars shows up.

In storyboards i'm using prototype cells.

## Update

I compile with latest settings of Xcode8(SDK ios 10) without modifiy or even open storyboards. Everything working fine. So I can asume anything on new Storyboard System is broken.

[image]

Comment: I guess this is a UITableView (and not a listview)? And please show the code how you load and set the image, in particuar for `tableView:cellForRowAt:`.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39851822/5669781

Comment: @Codo You are right. I edit the title.

Comment: @enoktate has a good hint. Are you using `cornerRadius`? I doubt his code is applicable directly though (UITableViewCell vs. regular layout). Please show your code.

Comment: BTW: It's very unlikely to be an XCode 8 issue. More likely, it occurs if you compile it against base SDK *iOS 10* (explicitly or implicitly by setting it to *latest*, which is *iOS 9* in XCode 7 and *iOS 10* in XCode 8).

Comment: @Codo I compile with latest  settings of Xcode8(SDK ios 10) without modifiy or even open storyboards. Everything working fine.